# Input with backslashes doesn't match regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression matcher, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
String input = "// source C:\\path\\to\\folder";
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("//\\s*source\\s+[a-zA-Z]:(\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+", input));
```

It returns `false` but it should pass. What is wrong with that regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslashes. That's what is wrong.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("//\\s*source\\s+[a-zA-Z]:(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+", input));
                                                              ^^
```

In regex, a backslash must be escaped—backslashed. That's two backslashes. Add to that, Java escaping and you must write four backslashes to match one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `\\\\` to match a backslash in Java regex:

```
String input = "// source C:\\path\\to\\folder";
boolean m = Pattern.matches("//\\s*source\\s+[a-zA-Z]:(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+", input);
//=> true
```

You need first escaping i.e. `\\` for String and another escaping i.e. `\\` for underlying regex engine to get a literal `\`.

Comment: I believe you meant that he should use ` \\\\ `?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `\\` in `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`:

```
String input = "// source C:\\path\\to\\folder";
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("//\\s*source\\s+[a-zA-Z]:(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-]+)+", input));
```